# How to reproduce audio files with i2s library and MAX98357A from SD file in ESP32?

Tags: audio, esp32, arduino-c++

I am developing a project with an ESP32 where after passing an NFC card through a module, it reads it and is supposed to play a .wav file stored in an SD that matches the NFC card. I looked into the ESP32-audioI2S library, and I thought I could use it.
The way you are supposed to reproduce a file in an SD with this library is like this:

```cpp
#include <Audio.h>
#include <FS.h>
#include <SD.h>

#define I2S_DOUT 25
#define I2S_BCLK 27
#define I2S_LRC 26

Audio audio;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  SPI.begin();
  if (!SD.begin()) {
    Serial.println("SD Card Mount Failed");
    return;
  }

  audio.setPinout(I2S_BCLK, I2S_LRC, I2S_DOUT);
  audio.setVolume(20);
  audio.connecttoFS(SD, "/audios/me llamo joaquin.wav"); // Select file to reproduce
}

void loop() { 
  audio.loop(); // Reproduce connected file
}
```

That works just fine. However, I want to be able to use other files. I thought I could just use the `audio.connecttoFS()` function inside the `loop()`. Still, no sound is reproduced when doing so.
I think that this library doesn't allow setting the file outside the `setup()`.

I got a way to reproduce the file, it is just not doing it "correctly". It reproduces way to fast, like it is sped up * 1000. Here's the code:

```cpp
#define I2S_DOUT 25
#define I2S_BCLK 27
#define I2S_LRC 26
void setup() {
// Start SD card and sqlite
  SPI.begin();
  if (!SD.begin()) {
    Serial.println("SD card not found");
    while (1) {};
  }
// Configure I2S
  i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
      .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_TX),
      .sample_rate = 44100,
      .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT,
      .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_RIGHT_LEFT,
      .communication_format = I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S_MSB,
      .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,
      .dma_buf_count = 2,
      .dma_buf_len = 1024,
      .tx_desc_auto_clear = true,
  };

  i2s_pin_config_t pin_config = {
      .bck_io_num = I2S_BCLK,
      .ws_io_num = I2S_LRC,
      .data_out_num = I2S_DOUT,
      .data_in_num = -1,
  };

  i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_0, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
  i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_0, &pin_config);
  i2s_set_dac_mode(I2S_DAC_CHANNEL_RIGHT_EN);
  i2s_set_sample_rates(I2S_NUM_0, 44100);
}

void loop() {
// Play the audio file
  string filename = "/audios/" + card->get_value() + ".wav";
  File file = SD.open(filename.c_str());
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
    return;
  }

  const size_t buffer_size = 512;
  uint8_t buffer[buffer_size];
  size_t bytes_read;
  size_t bytes_written;
  while (file.available() && (bytes_read = file.read(buffer, buffer_size)) > 0) {
    i2s_write(I2S_NUM_0, buffer, bytes_read, &bytes_written, portMAX_DELAY);
    if (bytes_read == 0) break;
  }
  file.close();
}
```

How can I make it reproduce the file "correctly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <driver/i2s.h>

#define I2S_DOUT 25
#define I2S_BCLK 27
#define I2S_LRC 26

i2s_config_t i2sConfig = {
    .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_TX),
    .sample_rate = 44100,
    .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT,
    .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_LEFT,
    .communication_format = I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S_MSB,
    .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,
    .dma_buf_count = 8,
    .dma_buf_len = 1024,
    .use_apll = false,
    .tx_desc_auto_clear = true,
};

i2s_pin_config_t pinConfig = {
    .bck_io_num = I2S_BCLK,
    .ws_io_num = I2S_LRC,
    .data_out_num = I2S_DOUT,
    .data_in_num = -1,
};

struct WavHeader {
  uint32_t sample_rate;
  uint16_t bits_per_sample;
  uint16_t num_channels;
};

File file;

bool parseWavHeader(File &file, WavHeader &header);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  SPI.begin();
  if (!SD.begin()) {
    Serial.println("SD Card Mount Failed");
    while (1) delay(1);
  }

  i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_0, &i2sConfig, 0, NULL);
  i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_0, &pinConfig);
}

void loop() {
  file = SD.open("/audios/me llamo joaquin.wav");
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
    while (1) delay(1);
  }

  WavHeader header;
  if (!parseWavHeader(file, header)) {
    Serial.println("Invalid WAV file");
    return;
  }

  i2s_set_sample_rates(I2S_NUM_0, header.sample_rate);

  const size_t buffer_size = 512;
  uint8_t buffer[buffer_size];
  size_t bytes_read;
  size_t bytes_written;
  while (file.available() && (bytes_read = file.read(buffer, buffer_size)) > 0) {
    i2s_write(I2S_NUM_0, buffer, bytes_read, &bytes_written, portMAX_DELAY);
    if (bytes_read == 0) break;
  }

  delay(1000);
}

bool parseWavHeader(File &file, WavHeader &header) {
  if (file.read() != 'R' || file.read() != 'I' || file.read() != 'F' || file.read() != 'F') {
    Serial.println("Invalid WAV file");
    return false;
  }

  file.seek(22);
  header.num_channels = file.read() | (file.read() << 8);
  header.sample_rate = file.read() | (file.read() << 8) | (file.read() << 16) | (file.read() << 24);
  file.seek(34);
  header.bits_per_sample = file.read() | (file.read() << 8);
  file.seek(44);  // Skip to the audio data
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [WAV Format](https://isip.piconepress.com/projects/speech/software/tutorials/production/fundamentals/v1.0/section_02/s02_01_p05.html), I see there are information in its header, which you should use in order to play the file "correctly".

That means you should first parse the WAV file header:

```cpp
struct WavHeader {
  uint32_t sample_rate;
  uint16_t bits_per_sample;
  uint16_t num_channels;
};

bool parseWavHeader(File &file, WavHeader &header) {
  if (file.read() != 'R' || file.read() != 'I' || file.read() != 'F' || file.read() != 'F') {
    return false;
  }
  file.seek(22);
  header.num_channels = file.read() | (file.read() << 8);
  header.sample_rate = file.read() | (file.read() << 8) | (file.read() << 16) | (file.read() << 24);
  file.seek(34);
  header.bits_per_sample = file.read() | (file.read() << 8);
  file.seek(44); // Skip to the audio data
  return true;
}
```

You can check and adapt that header, looking for instance at [`lixy123/ESP32-AUDIO-REC` `Wav.cpp`](https://github.com/lixy123/ESP32-AUDIO-REC/blob/master/Wav.cpp).

Then, update the `loop()` function to parse the WAV header and adjust the I2S configuration:

```cpp
void loop() {
  // Play the audio file
  string filename = "/audios/" + card->get_value() + ".wav";
  File file = SD.open(filename.c_str());
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
    return;
  }

  WavHeader header;
  if (!parseWavHeader(file, header)) {
    Serial.println("Invalid WAV file");
    file.close();
    return;
  }

  i2s_set_sample_rates(I2S_NUM_0, header.sample_rate);

  const size_t buffer_size = 512;
  uint8_t buffer[buffer_size];
  size_t bytes_read;
  size_t bytes_written;
  while (file.available() && (bytes_read = file.read(buffer, buffer_size)) > 0) {
    i2s_write(I2S_NUM_0, buffer, bytes_read, &bytes_written, portMAX_DELAY);
    if (bytes_read == 0) break;
  }
  file.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't work. It just makes 3 sounds and stops.

Comment: @Joaquin Yes you need to create a valid header then, not read it.